Will this be a tail call or not?
Is the recursive call in my code a tail call or is it just ordinary recursion?
void sum(const int values[], size_t count,int* result){
  if(count <= 0) return;
  *result += values[0];
  sum(values + 1,count - 1,result);
}

Because as far as I know, a tail call is recursion that occurs as the last call in a function.

Your understanding matches mine and the description of the tag you used. What makes you doubt?

If you compile this code with gcc or clang with -O3 to enable full optimizations, it will replace the recursion with a loop. So a tail recursion optimization is being applied.

not all compilers support tail recursion. It's simply an optimization. C standard says nothing about it

If no code follows a call, it's a tail call.
In C, this would like one of these:
void g( … );

void f( … ) {
   …
   g( … );  // Tail call.
}

void g( … );

void f( … ) {
   …
   g( … );  // Tail call.
   return;
   …
}

T g( … );

T f( … ) {
   …
   return g( … );  // Tail call.
   …
}

It has nothing to do with recursion, but it does include recursive calls.
Tail calls are interesting since they can be eliminated. C neither mandates nor forbids tail-call elimination. That's up to the compiler.

Ok, i see it, but what about calling function itself?

Already in the answer: "It has nothing to do with recursion, but it does include recursive calls."

Given that C does not require tail-call elimination/optimization, your safe strategy is to avoid recursion where it doesn't naturally fit (think of things like binary search trees).
In your specific case, there's no reason not to write:
void sum(const int *values, size_t count, int *result){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        *result += values[i];
    }
}

As an aside: it's interesting that you're using recursion but then modifying a pointer, which is very much not functional. This has the effect that for a sum to be accurate the value result points to must be initialized to 0 or the result will be inaccurate.

Your last point is true in most cases where ordinary recursion with a return value is converted to tail recursion with an accumulator parameter. Often there's a wrapper function that makes the first call with the appropriate initial value.
